# Django: FOO_set.all() for filter() instead of get()

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, set

I would like to look up reviews for items, which users have left in my Django app.

The models are quite simple:

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(_('Item'), max_length = 100,)
    ...

class ItemReview(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    review = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    ...
```

In my `template` I am listing the `items` which I pass to the `template` from the view function:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(name = ...)
```

In my template, I am listing the items like:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

**How can I display the `reviews` in the same loop? I have tried FOO_set.all, but it does not seem to work with the filter function.**

The problem seems very simple, but I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(_('Item'), max_length = 100,)
    ...

    def reviews(self):
        return ItemReview.object.filter(item=self)

class ItemReview(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    review = models.CharField(max_length = 140)


{% for item in items %}
<td>
    {{ item.name }}

    {% for review in item.reviews %}
        {{review}}
    {% endfor %}
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: When I try the for loop in the Django shell, I get the error message that `AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'itemreview_set'`. I did `a = Item.objects.all()`, `a[0].itemreview_set.all()`, which should be equivalent to your loop, right? But why do I get the error message then? When I try the code in the template, the `{{ review.review }}` is empty.